# Что означает "нам по пути"

Tags: выражения

Я заметила, что такое выражение часто слышится в популярных песнях.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста, конкретные примеры, с цитатами.
так же имейте ввиду, что данный сервис не предназначен для толкования лирики песен.

Answer (score 7):

В буквальном смысле, "(мы в движении, но) **нам** (с вами/тобою предстоит идти) **по** (одному и тому же) **пути**"; это намёк на возможность общения "в движении" (пойти вместе и по дороге поговорить или заняться общим делом). Поэтому в переносном смысле выражение означает: "*у нас общие интересы (взгляды)*", "*у нас есть повод для общения*" или даже, как в некоторых песнях, "*давай дружить*". Соответственно, выражение с отрицанием, "*нам не по пути*", выражает (сравнительно резкий) отказ от совместной деятельности.

Answer (score 4):

It means "we have a common path (or part of it), so we can go together".  The opposite is "нам не по пути" Examples:

- Садись в машину, я тебя подвезу до работы, нам по пути.
- В 12 лет я влюбился в одноклассницу. Каждый вечер я провожал её домой, хоть нам было и не по пути.
- Давай я тебя провожу до дома, нам по пути.

In songs, this probably means that a guy and a girl can be together. "Мне с тобой не по пути" means "I don't want be with you", "we do not click".

Answer (score 0):

Нам по пути буквально означает, что хоть и конечная цель путешествия может отличаться, направление движения общее и часть дороги можно проделать вместе. В переносном смысле под путём может подразумеваться какое-то общее дело, которое, имея общие цели, можно делать в сотрудничестве. Например, во Вторую мировую войну СССР по отношению к США могло сказать, что в деле уничтожения нацистов нам с вами по пути.